How to get a recent version of Bitcoin core for 32 bits?
Simple question. Modern wallet.dat whith bech32 addresses that can’t be opened by the last version of Bitcoin core compiled for 32 bits windows and was handed over a 2008 laptop with the money I got.


How to get a recent version of Bitcoin core for 32 bits?

One way is by compiling it from the source code.
At https://bitcoincoredocs.com/all.html it describes how to compile Bitcoin-core and says

After the bash shell is active, you can follow the instructions below, starting with the "Cross-compilation" section. Compiling the 64-bit version is recommended, but it is possible to compile the 32-bit version.
...
Build output expected:
...
3. windows 32-bit and 64-bit unsigned installers and dist zips (bitcoin-${VERSION}-win[32|64]-setup-unsigned.exe, bitcoin-${VERSION}-win[32|64].zip)

(my emphasis)
So I would expect that to produce, for example, bitcoin-28.0-win32.zip
I haven't tried this.

Related:

How to compile and conduct functional tests of Bitcoin core for CPU (32 bit) and memory constrained system?


In practice, get something like 10000 compiler errors to be fixed 1 by 1. Espescially for compiling Qt.
